# Как посмотреть план запроса в Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, производительность

У меня есть большой запрос, который очень долго работает. Мне требуется сильно его ускорить. Читал, что для этого стоит разобраться с планом запроса. Отсюда вопрос, как посмотреть план запроса?